How do you change figure dimensions in the qreport missChk function
In Rstudio I have a qmd file creating an HTML report. I'm using the missChk function from Frank Harrell's qreport package. My data structure has many variables and the names overlap in the plots so that they are unreadable. Is there any way to increase the size of the plots to help solve this?
I've tried altering fig-height in the code chunk eg
```
{r misscheck1}
#| results: asis
#| fig-width: 10
#| fig-height: 10

missChk(myData)
```

but it doesn't work.

Is your output html or pdf?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The output is html

I would try to add #| column: page to your chunk options, see here for more detail.

Thanks for the advice but this does not affect the size of the plots.
